# Errors of keeping the first 8 character of a string

Tags: c#, string, excel, substring

I'm very new to C# Winform programming. I want to read in a column of strings from Excel file. I defined a string called cusip, some cusip are empty, some are pure numbers, some are mixed of numbers and letters. After reading in each string, I want to keep only 8 characters if it's longer than 8, if the string is empty, I want to name it as "000000cm". The final step is add each string to a List, then do something else.

I keep getting error messages say "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on this line of code:

```
cusip.Substring(0,7).ToString();
```

Here is code snapshot:

```
string cusip; 
cusip = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, 3] as Excel.Range).Value2);

if (cusip != "")
{
    cusip.Substring(0,7).ToString();
}
    else cusip = "000000cm";

cusipList.Add(cusip);
```

Comment: cusip seems to be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `cusip.Substring(0,7).ToString();` doesn't change `cusip` and the empty check may also cause problems.

Change the code to:

```
string cusip; 
cusip = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, 3] as Excel.Range).Value2);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cusip))
{
    cusip = (cusip.Length > 7) ? cusip.Substring(0,8) : cusip;
} else {
    cusip = "000000cm";
}

cusipList.Add(cusip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string cusip = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, 3] as Excel.Range).Value2);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cusip))
{
    if (cusip.Length > 8)
    {
        cusip = cusip.Substring(0,8);
    }
}
else
{
    cusip = "000000cm";
}

cusipList.Add(cusip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string cusip = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, 3] as Excel.Range).Value2)??"";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cusip))
{
    cusip = cusip.Substring(0,8);
}
else
{
    cusip = "000000cm";
}

cusipList.Add(cusip);
```